# Stored procedure VS query output

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I try this SQL query

```
select 
    count(tblVV.PName) as total, 
    tblVV.PName
from 
    tblVV
inner join 
    tblRV on tblVV.MID = tblRV.ID
inner join 
    tblReg on tblRV.RID = tblReg.RID
where 
    tblReg.StartDate>= '2016-07-01 00:00:00' and
    tblReg.EndDate<= '2016-07-31 23:59:59' and
    tblReg.Region = 'uk' and
    tblRegionVehicles_Uni.RegNo = 'BE82' and 
    tblVV.PName <>''
group by 
    tblVV.PName
```

This shows result like this

```
total   PName
1      Sugar
11     Apple
```

Now when I create a stored procedure of same query like this

```
create procedure sp_ownerdata
    @fromdate datetime,
    @todate datetime,
    @region varchar,
    @RegNo varchar
as
    select 
        count(tblVV.PName) as total, 
        tblVV.PName
    from 
        tblVV
    inner join 
        tblRV on tblVV.MID = tblRV.ID
    inner join 
        tblReg on tblRV.RID = tblReg.RID
    where 
        tblReg.StartDate >= @fromdate and
        tblReg.EndDate <= @todate and
        tblReg.Region = @region and
        tblRegionVehicles_Uni.RegNo = @RegNo and 
        tblVV.PName <>''
    group by 
        tblVV.PName
```

and execute like this

```
execute sp_ownerdata '2016-07-01 00:00:00','2016-07-31 23:59:59','uk','BE82'
```

then this shows nothing where as I write correct parameters name and correct values I enter when I execute the stored procedure

```
 total  PName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem in parameters length

```
@region varchar,
@RegNo varchar
```

You need to specify proper length for `VARCHAR` parameters in stored procedure

```
@region varchar(10),
@RegNo varchar(10)
```